# Sibling Relationship Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog so I'm completely unaware of the errors i get. I'm making a code that describes the relationship between any two family members. 
i.e if two are married, sisters, brothers, sister and brother...etc.

```
wife(hussein,amina).
mother(amina,amira).
mother(amina,amany).
mother(amina,amna).
mother(amina,hassan).
mother(amina,hossam).

father(hussein,amira).
father(hussein,amany).
father(hussein,amna).
father(hussein,hassan).
father(hussein,hossam).

parent(X,Y):-
   mother(X,Y) ; father(X,Y).

married(X,Y) :- wife(X,Y).

sibling(X,Y) :-
   mother(Out1,X),
   father(Out2,X),
   mother(Out3,Y),
   father(Out4,Y),
   Out1 is Out3,Out2 is Out4.
```

The code works fine for the parent,married rules but i can't get why the sibling isn't working. I get for X and Y variables their mothers and make sure they're the same, their fathers and make sure they're the same to confirm they're siblings. but i get this error :

```
ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `amina/0' is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is/2` is for arithmetc; with is you can write something like

```
X is 3 + Y
```

so `X` is unified with 3 plus the arithmetic value of `Y`.

But, in you case, the terms you're using (`hussein`, `amina`, `amira`, etc.) aren't numbers so you can't use `is` for unify they.

You, in `sibling/2`, can "unify" `Out1` with `Out3` and `Out2` with `Out4` using a equal (`=` operator)

```
sibling(X,Y) :- 
  mother(Out1,X),
  father(Out2,X),
  mother(Out3,Y),
  father(Out4,Y),
  Out1 = Out3,
  Out2 = Out4.
```

or better (IMHO) usign the same variable (using `Out1` instead of `Out3` and `Out2` instead `Out4`)

```
sibling(X,Y) :- 
  mother(Out1,X),
  father(Out2,X),
  mother(Out1,Y),
  father(Out2,Y).
```

Comment: Thank you so much max66, both worked perfectly ! ;) .. appreciate the help :)

Comment: Is there no need of X\=Y?